# Filter array in rails with postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am struggling with filtering of an object in Rails 4.2.5 and Postgres.
At this moment I have lots of filters designed like this:

```
scope :occasions, -> (occasions) { where('occasions @> ?', "{#{occasions}}") }
scope :rating, -> (rating) { where('rating > ?', "#{rating}") }
```

Now I want to do more advanced object filtering for time and price. The object is stored in the database as an array (maximum size 48) like this:

```
time_slots = [null, null, null, 1500, 1500, 2000, 2000, 2500]
```

The above means that the person is not available on time slot 1, 2 and 3 and for next time slot the person costs 2000, etc.

I would like to filter on minTime, maxTime, minPrice and maxPrice.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you structure the time_slots?  put them in their own records in the db and find objects by matching time slot.  How are you storing them now?

Comment: I store them as an int array in the database

Comment: Can you structure them instead? Make a model and a db, store time and cost on each slot.

Comment: If I am correct, you can consider the fields as separate ones with `unnest(time_slots)`. Then you get 48 rows with values